# SQL Server Stored Procedure's Parameter has box character ( □ )?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I call the stored procedure from an ASP.Net web service using `ExecuteScalar()` function. The input value from the web service is correct as I wanted, no box character. But when passed to the SQL Server stored procedure, it became this (please notice the first row, the second row is correct, I intentionally added it just for comparison):

[image]

Using SQL Server Profiler, I see that the input parameter in the first row has incorrect box characters. When copied to a text editor, it shows up like I wanted. But the query result is not the same (the 1st is incorrect):

[image]

What could be the problem?

UPDATE: Stored Procedure signature (the parameter type is already NVARCHAR):

@PIT_NAME NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

Comment: Can you show us **(1)** the stored procedure signature (what parameters does it take), and **(2)** how you call this stored procedure - how are the parameters provided to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Please check couple of things

1. Trim the String before making the DB call
2. If Encoding could be the issue then please change the Storedproc parameter type to Nvarchar if it is varchar